# Fabric js - IText object allow re size but not scale

Tags: javascript, canvas, scale, fabricjs

I am using fabric js for my project, i wondered if its possible to allow the resizing of a text  field but not scale the content (font) within.

see example here:

http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html

The examples above seem to scale the text within the iText object.  But I want to resize the box itself, so when i make the text box bigger the text inside should go on to one line.

I  tried using the following options:

```
 lockScalingY: true,
 lockScalingX: false,
 lockUniScaling :false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you asking for has been developed under the name "fabric.Textbox".

```js
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(new fabric.Textbox('hello, im a resizable textbox, please feel free to resize me at will untill you meet size of the longest word', {width:250}))
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="400" height="400" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks, worked like a dream,   should point this option is only available in 1.6, not 1.5

Comment: It is in the 1.5.0 release, with tons of bugs. To make it work you have to build the library with modules=ALL options, is not a default module.

Comment: Hi @AndreaBogazzi, is there a posibility to disable vertical scaling of the text inside texbox when dragging the handles?

Comment: in the new version there is a control api that lets you define the behaviour of the corners. You need to write your own changeHeigh function, but you have to take care that this will reset everytime you change text, because as today this is the way fabric works. Please feel free top open an issue describing what are you trying to achieve, we have some extra people now and we are evaluating improvements all around